# EF 5 Beta 1 Code First - Sequence contains more than one element

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am attempting to upgrade my solution from the June 2011 CTP of EF Code First to EF 5 Beta.

I now have the following problem:

After creating an instance of the context, I get the exception listed below when I try and query the context.

It seems as if between the two versions of EF, something has changed whereby it is now having a problem with dealing with the configuration but I am at a loss in terms of where to start looking.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Paul.

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233079   Message=Sequence contains more than one element 
>   Source=System.Core   StackTrace:
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>          at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Navigation.NavigationPropertyConfiguration.Configure(DbDatabaseMapping
>   databaseMapping)
>          at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.<>c__DisplayClass36.<ConfigureAssociationMappings>b__35(NavigationPropertyConfiguration c)
>          at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.IEnumerableExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1
>   ts, Action`1 action)
>          at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.ConfigureAssociationMappings(DbDatabaseMapping
>   databaseMapping)
>          at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.Configure(EdmEntityType
>   entityType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest
>   providerManifest)
>          at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.ConfigureEntityTypes(DbDatabaseMapping
>   databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
>          at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.Configure(DbDatabaseMapping
>   databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
>          at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
>          at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext
>   internalContext)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ForceOSpaceLoadingForKnownEntityTypes()
>          at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()
>          at AccessAccounts.Accounts.DataAccess.Context.AccountsContext..ctor(String
>   connectionString) in c:\Source\EnterpriseVS11\Enterprise\Data Access
>   EF\Context\AccountsContext.cs:line 77
>          at AccessAccounts.BusinessService.Logon.LogonService.CheckDatabaseCompatibility()
>   in c:\Source\EnterpriseVS11\Enterprise\Business
>   Service\src\AccessAccounts\BusinessService\Logon\LogonService.cs:line
>   119
>          at AccessAccounts.BusinessService.Logon.LogonService.Logon(ApplicationTypes
>   applicationType, String databaseName, String userName, String
>   password, AuthenticationType authenticationMode) in
>   c:\Source\EnterpriseVS11\Enterprise\Business
>   Service\src\AccessAccounts\BusinessService\Logon\LogonService.cs:line
>   255
>          at SyncInvokeLogon(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
>          at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)   InnerException:

Comment: Can you provide the code around the query to the context? It looks like a problem with SingleOrDefault().

Comment: Seems that it's a known bug https://twitter.com/#!/divega/status/175984297931583489 - I'm encountering the very same thing, sadly.

Comment: @rafek  - thanks, I hope they fix it soon or can provide a work around.  If I get the time I may try and track down anyway what it is in the configuration it isn't liking, assuming that's the cause.  Am very keen to try EF 5 to see these performance improvements!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in EF5 Beta 1. We are going to fix this in Beta 2, which will be dropping within the next couple of weeks.

The bug only affects Independent Association (associations where the FK does not exist in your CLR classes) so you can workaround by switching to FK associations.

Comment: Thanks, looking forward to the fix.

Comment: I can confirm EF5 Beta 2 has fixed this.